# pass data from UITableCell to UITabView

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently working on a project that requires a list of customers to be displayed in a UITableView, the associated cell then segues to a TabView to display a detailed customer record in a tabbed ui.

I have setup the story board with the required TableView and populated fine. The TabViews all setup and I have added a custom class to the main TabView controller which can take the ID (required to interrogate service and return further data) and Customer Name. I have also added a UIViewController for the first tab in which I need to get the ID value.

I can't seem to get hold of the ID or Company Name that is passed. I have tried importing the .h file of the UITabView. I know the UITabView .h file is being populated with the values as in the .m file I am using the Customer Name to update the title of the Navigation Bar. However, whenever I breakpoint on line that gets the ID in the .m file for the individual tab, it always returns nil.

I am using the following code to try and get this value:

```
companyTabController *headerData = [companyTabController alloc];
_companyName_lbl.text = headerData.companyName; 
_companyID_lbl.text = headerData.ID;
```

I have tried several variations of the above and all to no avail.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but I think the first line needs to be `[[companyTabController alloc] init];`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought that after I posted and tried it, but still no joy.

Comment: try to initialize the companyTabController like [[CompanyTabController alloc]init];

Answer (score 7):

You can also use NSUserDefaults to save the data, I think that is the simplest way to save the data throughout the app.

Comment: Is the scope of NSUserDefaults not device-wide? I'd prefer to keep this sort of info 'in-app' where possible to limit potential access from 3rd parties. If the scope of NSUserDefaults is limited to the app then that may well be a plan. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted, the `headerData` is a new instance. So the `companyName` and the `ID` will be nil unless you assign some value to them.

Since, you mentioned that you are able update the navigation bar title, try using the same object for fetching the values in this controller as well. (Maybe you can use a singleton object)

Answer (score 0):

If your segueing you have to use the prepareForSegue:sender: method as such:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
companyTabController *companyTC = [segue destinationViewController];
companyTC.companyName_lbl.text = headerData.companyName;
etc
}
```

if your not segueing you will have to instantiate it as such :

```
- (void) didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
companyTabController *companyTC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CopmanyTabController"];
companyTC.companyName_lbl.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text or = headerData.companyName;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:companyTC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: make sure companyName_lbl is a synthesized property in the tab view, it doesn't have to be an outlet if your just passing data.

Comment: That is how I am passing the name to the title, however it won't reach beyond that first VC.

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer to include the .text for labels try that. If that doesn't work you either aren't segueing your view controllers correctly or don't have your properties synthesized in your second view controller. Is headerdata.company name returning nil?

Comment: Yes, both values returned as nil in the second VC. Fine in the first. I have thrown the value in NSUserDefaults at the moment which has got me over the hump but I will probably need a better solution long term. I'll have a look at the segues

Comment: Your issue lies where @Dheeraj pointed out. If you pass nothing you'll get nothing. For example just change to this line and it will pass companyTC.companyName_lbl.text =@"Apple Inc"; it will pass. But you can't pass nothing and expect to retrieve something. How are you setting company name from header data? And your right NSUserdedaults is not the way to go

Comment: The value is passed in the prepare segue method from the TableView and does correctly land in the TabViewController. Confirmed by both the fact the NavigationBar title is updated and I have stepped through in debug and I can see it.

It looks as though the import of the companyTabController is generating a new instance of the class rather than re-using the class with the value filled. Which is what @Dheeraj is saying. I figured that [[companyTabController alloc] init]; would call the same instance no matter which VC I called it from.

Comment: My background is in web development via vb.net where I can get away with this, but the concept of the MVC model and Obj-C is new to me with new concepts, so apologies if any of this seems way off... The theory is sound in my head at least haha

Comment: I get what you are saying but how are initially defining company name in header data?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *companyName;

However, I have just realised that this should perhaps be (nonatomic, retain)? That way I can access from any class that call this class?